# How to solve highest combined total between arrays?

Tags: algorithm, performance, big-o, dynamic-programming, coding-efficiency

1. There is 3 arrays: miners, minersLevel, oresMined
2. Each Miner can only mine an ore once but only at the minersLevel or below it
3. What is the biggest total amount of ores the miners can mine?

```
miners = [10, 1, 7, 9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 2, 3]
minersLevel = [9, 2, 4, 5, 1, 9, 2, 4, 2, 7]
oresMined = [7, 9, 9, 4, 8, 7, 10, 4, 10, 8]


output: 96
internally represented as [10, 8, 10, 10, 10, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10] = 96
```

Q) How would I tackle this problem such that the speed (nanoseconds) is the fastest possible, I could brute force between each miner and then checking with each level and keeping track of the highest oreMined so far then take the highest at the end but this would be O(n^2) and is too slow.

Another edge case I thought would be finding the lowest minersLevel to highest oresMined, if it is minersLevel = 1 and OresMined = 10 then the max is 100 by default, but then how would I tackle the other levels?

Note that sorting would also take too much time. The arrays are usually 10 in length with element values going from 1 to 10.

Comment: What do the three input arrays represent?  For example, what does miners[0] represent?  It may also help to understand the problem if you could give your brute force code for solving the problem.

Comment: miners[0] is level 10, he can mine any ore at 10 or below, we want the highest ore value he can mine which is 10 since there is a minersLevel[7] = 2  with its corresponding oresMined[7] = 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting your code in Python:

```py
miners = [10, 1, 7, 9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 2, 3]
minersLevel = [9, 2, 4, 5, 1, 9, 2, 4, 2, 7]
oresMined = [7, 9, 9, 4, 8, 7, 10, 4, 10, 8]

sum = 0
oreArray = [0]*len(miners)
for i in range(len(miners)):
    highestOre = -1
    for j in range(len(minersLevel)):
        if(minersLevel[j] <= miners[i]):
            # we can mine this ore
            if(oresMined[j] > highestOre):
                highestOre = oresMined[j]
    sum = sum + highestOre
    oreArray[i] = highestOre

print sum,oreArray
```

This gives the answers you gave in O(n^2) time.

You can do this in O(n) time as follows:

```py
m = max(max(minersLevel),max(miners))
# Create B so B[i] will store the highest value ore for a mine of level i
B = [0] * (m+1) 
for i,v in enumerate(oresMined):
    lev = minersLevel[i] # Level of the mine
    B[lev] = max(B[lev],v)
# Now create C array so C[i] stores the highest value ore for a mine of level i or less
highestOre = 0
C=[]
for v in B:
    highestOre = max(highestOre,v)
    C.append(highestOre)
# Now go through miners and find optimum result
oreArray = []
sum = 0
for lev in miners:
    v = C[lev]
    sum += v
    oreArray.append(v)

print sum,oreArray
```

The idea is to create two auxiliary arrays.

1. B[i] will store the highest value ore for a mine of level i
2. C[i] stores the highest value ore for a mine of level i or less

Once we have these arrays, we can simply go through the miners and lookup the best answer for each.

Comment: Because the array sizes are 10 in length with random numbers between 1 and 10, my O(n^2) is actually faster, perhaps the max methods and using enumerate, .append here is costing too many nano seconds?